# how can i send mysql database table in a nice tabular format to slack

Tags: python, mysql, slack

use this code  :

```
def test():
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=rds_host, user=name, password=password, db=db_name, charset='utf8')
    curs = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    sql = "sql"
    curs.execute(sql)
    da = curs.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=da, columns=['sale_date', 'total_amt'])
    df['total_amt'] = df['total_amt']
    slack_message = {
        'text': tabulate(df, tablefmt="fancy_grid",headers='keys',stralign='left')
    }
    req = Request(HOOK_URL, json.dumps(slack_message).encode('utf-8'))
    try:
        response = urlopen(req)
        response.read()
        logger.info("Message posted")
    except HTTPError as e:
        logger.error("Request failed: %d %s", e.code, e.reason)
    except URLError as e:
        logger.error("Server connection failed: %s", e.reason)
```

when i run the code in pycharm, it ran well
pycharm output:
[image]

slack output:
[image]

slack output(added column in korean):
[image]

Comment: The data is exactly the same.  The difference is that slack is not using a fixed-space font.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that for formatting regular text (so what you write in the chat), Slack doesn't use fixed-space font. This means that the output won't be aligned (as you have experienced).

To fix this, you should wrap the portion of the message you're trying to format properly inside ```. This will tell Slack to use a code block to format the content, which has fixed-space font and it should behave the same way as it does in the output of Pycharm.

So looking at your code, you would have to add something along the lines of:

````py
...
slack_message = {
        'text': f'```{tabulate(df, tablefmt="fancy_grid",headers='keys',stralign='left')}```'
    }
...
````

Depending on the version of Python you're using, f-strings might not be available. If that is the case, use some other supported formatting functionality instead.

Comment: when i use f-string it look like good so i am glad to say thank you and can i have another question ?..
um.. i have to add a column in korean but when i add column
it look like above slack output so what can i do for solving this issue?
Sorry to keep asking..

Comment: I can't think of an idea why adding korean language would influence the way Slack formats messages inside ``` blocks, so I would suggest you check how the `tabulate(...)` handles this.

Comment: i added output above : slack output(added column in korean